# Can I reuse carpet underlayment pad?

Tags: carpet, underlayment

I recently ripped off the old carpet in a room, along with the under-pad. The pad is in a decent condition, so I'm wondering it could be the re-used somewhere? Of course I would not use it again for another carpet underlayment, but is it possible to insulate anything with it (just as example)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would not bother with used pad . You can get new inexpensive rubber pad of the appropriate thickness  when you need it.  I have reused older type pads , you can never get them clean; dirt goes through the carpet into the pad. And , I have used new pad trimmings for attic supplemental insulation , again ,the used pads are dirty.

Comment: And used pad often voids the carpet warranty.